# When to use a class instead of a dict

Tags: python

User data, as follows:

```
user = {"id": 1, "firstName": "Bar", "surname": "Foosson", "age": 20}
```

is sent to an application via json.

In many places in the code the following it done:

```
user["firstName"] + " " + user["surname"]
```

which leads me to believe a function should be used:

```
def name(user):
    return user["firstName"] + " " + user["surname"]
```

which in turn leads me to believe that the code should be refactored with the use of a `User` class instead, with a `name` method. Do you agree and is there any argument for not refactoring the code to use a class instead?

Comment: Aside, Use `"{firstName} {surname}".format(**user)`. ;)

Comment: Another aside: in Python, these things are called "dicts" (their type is `dict`); calling them "maps" can be confusing (because of `map`).

Comment: I would use a class even if there was no need for `def name(user)`. As a general rule, if the keys of the `dict` are fixed (you always expect to have firstName, surname), that is an indication that you should probably not use a `dict`.

Comment: @Bhargav Rao What if someone accidentally wrote "{firstName}  {surname}".format(**user), where by accident there are two spaces between "}" and "{"? Surely user.name() is better.

Comment: `dict` can't contain methods, can they now? Only attributes.

Comment: @Baz what if someone accidentally wrote two spaces in `"  "`? Surely Bhargav is right. Be like Bhargav.

Comment: @bereal I thought Bhargav Rao meant he would use "{firstName} {surname}".format(**user) instead of user.name(), but I presume now he meant he would use this instead of user["firstName"] + " " + user["surname"] :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you are hesitant to use classes because of the need to write boilerplate code.

But there's a nice library that may make your life easier: [`attrs`](https://attrs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Glyph has a post with a self-speaking title: [The One Python Library Everyone Needs](https://glyph.twistedmatrix.com/2016/08/attrs.html). Of course, it's an opinionated piece, but here's a quote from its [Examples page](https://attrs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html):

> ```
> >>> @attr.s
> ... class Coordinates(object):
> ...     x = attr.ib()
> ...     y = attr.ib()
> ```
>
> By default, all features are added, so you immediately have a fully functional data class with a nice `repr` string and comparison methods.
>
> ```
> >>> c1 = Coordinates(1, 2)
> >>> c1
> Coordinates(x=1, y=2)
> >>> c2 = Coordinates(x=2, y=1)
> >>> c2
> Coordinates(x=2, y=1)
> >>> c1 == c2
> False
> ```

It's a quite handy library, so check it out.

Here's an example of your `User` class:

```
import attr

@attr.s
class User(object):

    id = attr.ib()
    firstName = attr.ib()
    surname = attr.ib()
    age = attr.ib()

    @property
    def name(self):
        return '{0.firstName} {0.surname}'.format(self)

user_dict = {'id': 1, 'firstName': 'Bar', 'surname': 'Foosson', 'age': 20}
user = User(**user_dict)
assert user.name == 'Bar Foosson'
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are great for storage and retrieval, but if you need more functionality on top of that, a class is usually the way to go. That way you can also assure certain attributes are set, etc.

For your situation, if a user's attributes are read-only, my approach would actually be using [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). You get immutability of attributes, memory efficiency, and you can still set `name` to a pre-defined method to be used just like you'd use `property` on a class:

```
from collections import namedtuple

@property
def name(self):
    return '{} {}'.format(self.firstName, self.surname)

User = namedtuple('User', 'id firstName surname age')
User.name = name

user = User(1, 'Bar', 'Foosson', 20)
print(user.name)  # Bar Foosson

user = User(2, 'Another', 'Name', 1)
print(user.name)  # Another Name
```